# how do you create a design system culture in your team

Tags: culture

Design systems are gaining a lot of popularity lately, especially with invisions design system manager coming up next month However setting up these tools are only half the battle according to even pioneers who did this.

https://www.invisionapp.com/blog/design-systems-expert-advice/

it seems only when the team or company is as a certain stage of their product or design that implementing a design system will make sense. also there many ways of getting the team involved and invested so that every members starts to embrace using and maintaining it.

what would be some ways of getting your whole team onboard in order to make sure the design system is embraced and used by everyone in the team

e.g. one exercise mentioned was to carry out a ui element audit across the product

Comment: In what way does the information in your linked blog post not suit your current environment?

Comment: Are you the leader/manager of the team?

Answer (score 0):

I think design system is more helpful in the product based company where there are lots of screens and could be multiple products. When there are multiple designers working on a huge product it becomes really hard to keep track of design style of each element, especially microelements like inputs and generic icons. If you do not document it proper your design can easily be inconsistent. This can happen a lot in remote teams. So with design systems, yeah it takes time to document each and everything, but it is like once you document it and make it available for everyone in the team, it becomes easy for everyone to just use it when it is needed again. Also, it is not something which is documented by just one person, it is like github sort of thing for designing where the whole team can contribute and keep track of each design element. This helps a lot in not only designing the consistent interface but also reduces the time to rework or finding the pre designed elements.